# Customize or remove NSIS uninstaller prompt

Tags: nsis

Is there a way to customize (call a custom plugin) or even completely remove the NSIS uninstaller prompt `Would you like to proceed with uninstall?` by adding a directive or any other piece of magic to the NSIS script?

I have also tried passing either of the `/q` or `/s` to the `uninstall.exe` with no effect.

Comment: Silent switch is /S...

Comment: @Anders - Unfortunately, /S doesn't work either. It's good for silent install but not for uninstall. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a normal NSIS message, did you use a generator or template to create your script?

You should be able to find the `MessageBox` in your script source and remove it (Or set a default for silent mode)

Comment: Damn, I missed that completely. You were absolutely right. Thanks!